# Why TEMPLATEPATH return absolute path to child directory?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using framework for develop theme for wordpress. after install framework i create child theme and include files from my framework in functions.php.

In 2 other projects all works fine, but in my new project i have an error. When i call TEMPLATEPATH it back absolute path to child directory, but it must return a path to parent theme.

What can be wrong?

P.S. Framework use TEMPLATEPATH to include his own files, so i need to understand how can i  fix this problem.

Comment: You should use STYLESHEETPATH on a child theme - here's some useful information http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21086/wordpress-include-templatepath-or

Comment: Hi, @McNab.  

Thank you for quick respond.  

I can use STYLESHEETPATH in my functions.php in child theme, but i can't change TAMPLATEPATH to STYLESHEETPATH in a framework files(framework author doesn't allow to do this). So i need to find how i can fix problems with TAMPLATEPATH.

Comment: The framework developer must have included or documented a way to do this, otherwise the framework is no use. Look instead at get_template_directory_uri() http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri or get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri then maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution of my problem.
I got wrong path to parent theme because in DB in table "wp_options" in field   "template" was a child theme name. When i changed value of this field to parent theme name, the TEMPLATEPATH start return a path to parent theme.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `get_template_directory_uri()` to get the parent theme directory like so:

```
 echo get_template_directory_uri()/img/icon.png
```

If you want to get something out of your child theme directory you can use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

**More info:**

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

*Edit: Just noticed **McNab**'s reply in the comments of the question, give this guy some upvotes as well. :)*

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I created my child theme first and had it activated BEFORE creating my parent themes style.css file.

All you have to do to fix this is Activate any other theme, then reactivate your child theme. This will correct the 'template' value in the wp_options table.